# Where can I download the hash of an OpenBSD release ISO?

Tags: openbsd

To check that it's 100% ok, and to check that it doesn't containt anything "bad" :)

I tried [to google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&q=inurl%3Ahttps+install49.iso+SHA256&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=) but with no luck. Of course it's need to be downloaded over a secure connection, HTTPS!

Thank you!

Comment: For a quick and dirty look, have a dig around in [here](http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/OpenBSD/).

Comment: [Do not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073), please read our [FAQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq). The [version on Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/where-to-download-openbsd-release-isos-over-https) is (marginally) better worded and has several answers already, so I'm voting to close this one.

Answer (score 1):

The SHA256 checksums for OpenBSD releases are available in the same folder on the http/ftp servers you downloaded the iso image from.

Comment: I asked about HTTPS.

Comment: You only get https if the mirror you use provides https, which most do not. You can check the integrity of your mirror by using the checksum from a different mirror if you like. Otherwise, move on to more important problems. If somebody compromised the release structure and all the mirrors have a bogus release with bad checksum files, serving them up over https wouldn't save anybody!